# Entity framework throws Exception when executing via SqlQuery a CTE

Tags: sql, entity-framework-5, common-table-expression

When I debug over these lines of code looking into the query variable I can see a System.Data.EntityException:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'UnitId'. A member of the type, 'ITMS.Unit', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

```
var query = context.Units.SqlQuery("WITH x(Id) AS
  (SELECT @UnitId UNION ALL SELECT Unit.UnitId
  FROM Unit JOIN x ON Unit.ParentId = x.Id ) " +
  "DELETE Unit FROM x JOIN Unit ON Unit.UnitId = x.Id",
  new SqlParameter("UnitId", unit.UnitId));
```

The raw SQL executed in Sql Management studio runs fine.

What is the problem of this datareader? Hm... Actually I do a select but after it a delete... which is a non-query. Is that the problem?
Btw. I use code first.

**UPDATE**

I have updated and corrected the exception message.

Adding the @-symbol to the SqlParameter name "@UnitId" did not help.

Although this exception happens the UnitId and its children are deleted !!!

Seems someone else had the same problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/17bdad58-93dd-4ba8-8a60-5177f3ce4a88

Comment: Also try to change `SqlParameter("UnitId", unit.UnitId));` To `SqlParameter("@UnitId", unit.UnitId));` with the `@` prefix for the parameter name. ???

Comment: Which UnitId are you trying to send to the query? Or is UnitId for the result?

Comment: The UnitId is the id of the unit I want to delete and all children which has this unitId as parentId.

Comment: @Jeff UnitId is a "input" parameter for the Delete command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SqlParameter declaration is incorrect. First, the parameter name needs an @ in front of it (in the query as well). Second, the overloaded constructor you are using is regularly confused with the constructor:

```
public SqlParameter(
    string parameterName,
    SqlDbType dbType
)
```

And, you are calling the wrong method to execute a query. SqlQuery assumes the SQL returns data that needs to be mapped to entities. So I'd change the code to:

```
var parm = new SqlParameter("@UnitId", SqlDbType.Int);
parm.Value = unit.UnitId
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("WITH x(Id) AS
  (SELECT @UnitId UNION ALL SELECT Unit.UnitId
  FROM Unit JOIN x ON Unit.ParentId = x.Id ) " +
  "DELETE Unit FROM x JOIN Unit ON Unit.UnitId = x.Id", parm);
```

Make sure to set the SqlDbType in the SqlParameter constructor appropriately; I assumed 32-bit integer for my sample.

Comment: I did both suggestions from you. The only thing that changed is that I get the same exception message but another exception type: EntityCommandExecutionException. There seems to be a problem with the name of the property and the name of the field in the reader. Anyone knows more?

Comment: It seems the SqlQuery method really wants to return a Units because its a query... but Delete is a non-query so I can not use the SqlQuery method.

Comment: I am still waiting for TAbleValueFunctions in Code First prolly EF 8.0... So far: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Recursive-or-hierarchical-bf43a96e

Comment: Thanks your code correction works. Having Sql in my repository feels not good. OK as long its sql understood by oracle/sql etc I can live with it. When Code first approach improves I will fix this ExecuteSqlCommand too :)

Comment: I agree it doesn't feel good. But there are certain problems that I don't think will ever really fit into any ORM much less EF which does feel more restrictive than most.